# Filter list of object Using Java 8 and Map the filtered results back to the same list

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list that contains list of objects and I want to retrieve only active records from the list. Below is the code which I'm trying but it is not filtering properly.

```
 private List<SkuList> getActiveSkuListsAndSkuListLineItem(List<SkuListEntity> skuListEntityList) {
return skuListEntityList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListStatus.ACTIVE.getId()))
    .map(x -> x.getSkuListLineItems())
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListLineItemStatus.ACTIVE.getId())))
    .map(x -> x.getSkuListEntity())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .stream().map(x -> skuListMapper.toSkuListResource(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The above code is retrieving all the records irrespective of the filter (ACTIVE) condition.
If I break the above code like below :

```
skuListEntityList = skuListEntityList.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListStatus.ACTIVE.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

 List<SkuListLineItemEntity> skuListLineItemEntityList = skuListEntityList.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> x.getSkuListLineItems().stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListLineItemStatus.ACTIVE.getId())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then `skuListEntityList` and `skuListLineItemEntityList` objects contain only active records. What's wrong I'm doing above when I have consolidated the logic in one return statement.

Comment: which ACTIVE check fails? it seems that your equals check is not working. have you debugged it to check this?

Comment: Not really clear without the proper entity definitions and description, which check is failing and which is not.

Comment: As I understand you are filtering on 2 points: one for getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey() / SkuListStatus.ACTIVE and other for again getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey() / SkuListLineItemStatus.ACTIVE.   Why filter the same field twice using 2 different comparison sources ?   To make it clear you might put dummy class and definitions here to work on.

Comment: A great example on how not to use streams.

Comment: @firegloves Yes I have checked that and equals method is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to test your code without the actual classes but there is alot of added noise in your first stream.

Your original code is below with added comments to hopefully clear up some of the extra noise you've added.

```
return skuListEntityList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListStatus.ACTIVE.getId()))
    .map(x -> x.getSkuListLineItems())
    .flatMap(x -> x.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListLineItemStatus.ACTIVE.getId())))
    .map(x -> x.getSkuListEntity())//remove and simply operate on x below
    .collect(Collectors.toList())//This is not needed as you're already working with a stream
    .stream()//This is not needed as you're already working with a stream
    .map(x -> skuListMapper.toSkuListResource(x/*x.getSkuListEntity() remove map above*/)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your answer should look something more along the lines of this. Although without the fleshed out classes I can't guarantee your logic is working as you intend it to.

```
        return skuListEntityList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListStatus.ACTIVE.getId()))
                .flatMap(x -> x.getSkuListLineItems().stream())
                .filter(s -> s.getStatusTypDbky().getTypDbkey().equals(SkuListLineItemStatus.ACTIVE.getId()))
                .map(x -> skuListMapper.toSkuListResource(x.getSkuListEntity()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would suggest reading 
https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap
and 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html
To understand exactly what you're doing in each intermediate operation.

If you're confused on exactly what is happening, remove the method chaining and use a debugger to see the *actual* returned value from the calls.

ie.

```
Stream<SkuListEntity> skuListEntityStream = skuListEntityList.stream();
Stream<SkuListEntity> filteredSkuListEntityStream = skuListEntityStream.filter();
...
```